# Setting the value of an imput box - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'd like to know how to manually set a value to that box, similar to how I'd write it on the keyboard. The box itself doesn't have an ID so I can't use `getElementById.value` or `.innerHTML` so I'm kinda stuck.

Here's a picture for reference.
[image: http://i.imgur.com/zxKkf1w.png]

Basically what I want to do is go to console and set the value of that box equal to 123 for example, without having to click on it with my mouse and type it on the keyboard. Something like `getElementByID.value = 15` for instance.

Thank you

Comment: `document.getElementsByName('buy_wood')[0].value = '15'` Please just post your code next time.

Comment: Works! Thanks a bunch man, sorry I'm kinda new to this :)

Comment: @choz it will only work if there is only one element named 'buy_wood'.

Comment: Actually, you have some errors in the Chrome console. Please, check the errors in there.

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez yup fixed, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$('*[data-resource="wood"]').val(the_value)
```

Comment: This appears to work as well but it triggers the field below it as well, thereby adding the same value to both which kinda glitches it out.

Comment: @Zaiton - it that works for you, you haven't tagged the question appropriately, as the "jQuery" tag is missing, and this answer is in fact wrong because of that.

Comment: @adeneo woops, sorry man.

Answer (score 0):

if you dont have id , then you can use the following code

```
var a= document.getElementsByTagName("input")[i];

var a=document.getElementsByName("buy_wood");

var a=document.getElementsByClassName("premium-exchange-input");
```

Comment: I did but I couldn't change the value for some reason.

Comment: can you share a code

Comment: it's cool mate choz found the solution. Thanks for the help